# Update query error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update records in table **tciSTran** that are present in the table **tarRecurInvcLineDS**

Here is the query I wrote...

```
 update [mas500_test_app].[dbo].[tciSTaxTran] 
 set STaxSchdKey = 310
 where STaxTranKey in
 (select STaxTranKey  from [mas500_test_app].[dbo].[tarRecurInvcLineDs]
```

I'm getting this error

`Unable to update the tciSTaxTran record because it is trying to reference a record in tciSTaxSchedule that does not exist.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have a foreign key between tciSTaxTran.STaxSchdKey and the tciSTaxSchedule table.  Does the tciSTaxSchedule table have a row with a primary key of `310`?